# Android Scene Transition Animation when starting multiple activities

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, activity-transition

I'd like to use ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation to do a scene transition between 2 UI elements but I also need to start multiple activities. This code causes issues (prevents the second activity from even starting). I can start the activities individually to pass the options to the correct activity, but that has its own issues with a flickering UI. Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
if (targetActivity == TargetActivity.HOMEPAGE) {
        baseActivity.startActivity(homeIntent)
    } else {
        val targetIntent = argumentBuilder.toIntent(baseActivity, targetActivity.clazz)
        val intents = arrayOf(homeIntent, targetIntent)

        val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(baseActivity, view.targetUserImage, "transition_to_inbox")
        baseActivity.startActivities(intents, options.toBundle())
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't supported. The framework is designed to transition from one Activity to another within the same task. If you start multiple activities, it has no idea what you intend with respect to UI elements.

Comment: Could I potentially do something with artificially constructing the activity backstack after starting my activity? There's a little bit of detail about that here, but its kinda thin. https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Comment: You can do that if you use Fragment Transitions instead of Activity Transitions. Unfortunately, you can't chain shared elements between Activities.

Comment: Got it, well thanks for answering! Always good to hear from someone at Google.